# How to prevent TypeError on v-text-field enter key up

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following Vuetify form with single v-text-field and a button:

```
<v-form v-model="valid" ref="form" @submit.prevent>
      <v-container>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex
            xs12
            md8
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="name"
              :rules="nameRules"
              :counter="max"
              maxlength='max'
              :label="$t('Save new name')"
              required
              clearable
              @keyup.enter.prevent='onEnterPressed'
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex
            xs12
            md4
          >
            <v-btn
              :loading="saving"
              :disabled="!valid || saving"
              color="info"
              @click="processNewName"
            >
              <v-icon left dark>fa-save</v-icon>
              {{ $t('Save') }}
            </v-btn>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
```

Currently these are my methods:

```
onEnterPressed() {
  console.log('enter pressed');
},
processNewName() {
  ...
}
```

I'm using `@submit.prevent` to stop refreshing the page when the Enter button is hit.

So far everything seems to be working. However, when I hit the enter button, in the console I'm getting this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at e.setFieldValue (onloadwff.js:71)
at HTMLFormElement.formKeydownListener (onloadwff.js:71)
```

In onloadwff.js the error points to the following code:

```
if("password"===r.type)
```

So `r` is undefined. How can I prevent this from happening? I already tried to use `@keyup.enter.prevent.native`, tried `@keydown.enter.prevent`, tried to point `@submit.prevent` to `processNewName` method... This error keeps showing up.

I checked in Vuetify site the v-text-field component, and it seems that sometimes they also get this error in some of their examples, but not all of them. But I can't figure out what to do to prevent this from happening. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Upon further investigation I fount out that `onloadwff.js` belongs to LastPass plugin. Checked in different browser without that plugin and saw everything works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**This error comes from your LastPass plugin** and it is discussed on Github on various frameworks:

- [vuejs/vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/236#issuecomment-262287678)
- [KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill/issues/351)
- [mui-org/material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14860)
- [SAP/openui5](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2535)

It's not the best solution, it's more like a **workaround**, but for now I either:

- Disable LastPass
- Avoid using `<v-form>`